# Help a man to recover his PIN

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

A man forgot his 6 digits PIN, but fortunately he remembered the clue for his PIN.

> - The n-th digit is the first digit of (product of other digits multiplied by n)
> - The number is not 000000

If the PIN is abcdef, then :

The 1st digit = The first digit of $1 × b × c × d × e × f$ 
The 2nd digit = the first digit of $2 × a × c × d × e × f$ 
 
...
The 6th digit = The first digit of $6 × a × b × c × d × e$

What is his PIN?

Comment: PIN number,  ATM machine, NIC card ... uggh!  It's just a PIN.  It stands for Personal Identification Number.  :)

Comment: I've often thought it would be amusing to write a story in which all those phrases appear but they are actually used correctly. A gang of criminals have an ATM machine (a machine that makes ATMs) to make special fake ATMs that record PINs, so then if they have a PIN number they can look up that position on the list to find the PIN. Etc. But it was never amusing *enough* for me actually to sit down and write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His PIN is

> **529311**
>
>  `a=5; 1×b×c×d×e×f = 1x2x9x3x1×1 = 54`
>  `b=2; 2×a×c×d×e×f = 2x5x9x3x1×1 = 270`
>  `c=9; 3×a×b×d×e×f = 3x5x2x3x1×1 = 90`
>  `d=3; 4×a×b×c×e×f = 4x5x2x9x1×1 = 360`
>  `e=1; 5×a×b×c×d×f = 5x5x2x9x3×1 = 1350`
>  `f=1; 6×a×b×c×d×e = 6x5x2x9x3×1 = 1620`

Comment: +1. Brute force alone, or was there an analytic step?

Comment: I believe this is solvable, but it looked much easier to brute-force so I did.